# Android bluetooth socket closed but still working for sending serial data

Tags: android, multithreading, sockets, io, bluetooth

So I have set up a serial connection between a paired raspberry pi device running a pybluez rfcomm-server. I have paired my Android device to the Pi, and then put together a Bluetooth service that leverages a Thread to handle the two-way asynchronous comms. Most of the code is straight from the Android Developers Guides on Bluetooth Socket communication [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ConnectingAsAClient) and reading/writing to the socket as discussed [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#ManagingAConnection)

The issue arises when I manually disconnect from the Pi by closing down my    socket and closing down the thread handling the communication. I can reconnect, spin up another thread, and successfully start communicating with the Pi again **but this is where it gets weird**, IOExcpetions start getting thrown and Logcat is pissing and moaning that and "Error occured sending data". The exception is caught obviously and like I said earlier, the Pi is still happily receiving the messages. I can repeat this by disconnecting and reconnecting again and again.

Normally I would just shrug and move on because it works right? But I don't feel like any IOExceptions should be being thrown.

Here is some code:

*(BtBus is an RxJava based message bus I made, all messages are send on background threads and received on the main thread)*

BluetoothService - connect() and disconnect() methods

```
public void connect(){
    if(btAdapter == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No bluetooth adapter available");
    }
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = btAdapter.getBondedDevices();

    if (pairedDevices.size() > 0) {
        // There are paired devices. Get the name and address of each paired device.
        for (BluetoothDevice device : pairedDevices) {
            if(device.getName().contains("raspberry")){
                pi = device;
                Log.d(TAG, "using paired device: " + pi.getName());
                break;
            }
        }
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No BT devices paired");
    }
    if(pi != null) {
        if(btAdapter.isDiscovering())
            btAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        Observable.fromCallable(this::connectSocket)
                .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(socket -> {
                    if(socket != null){
                        try {
                            socket.connect();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Socked with device created, creating thread");
                            connectedThread = new ConnectedThread(socket);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Thread created, starting...");
                            connectedThread.start();
                            Log.d(TAG, "Thread Started");
                            isConnected = true;
                            BtBus.publish(new BtAction("CONNECTION_ESTABLISHED"));
                        }catch (IOException e) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Unable to connect socket");
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }

//disconnect
public void disconnect() {
    if(socket != null) {
        connectedThread.cancel();
    }
}
private BluetoothSocket connectSocket(){
    try {
        socket = pi.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(DEFAULT_UUID);
        return socket;
    }catch (IOException e){
        Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get service with Pi UUID");
        return null;
    }
}
```

ConnectedThread

```
private class ConnectedThread extends Thread {
    private final BluetoothSocket mmSocket;
    private final InputStream mmInStream;
    private final OutputStream mmOutStream;
    private byte[] mmBuffer; // mmBuffer store for the stream

    private ConnectedThread(BluetoothSocket socket) {
        mmSocket = socket;
        InputStream tmpIn = null;
        OutputStream tmpOut = null;

        // Get the input and output streams; using temp objects because
        // member streams are final.
        try {
            tmpIn = socket.getInputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating input stream", e);
        }
        try {
            tmpOut = socket.getOutputStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when creating output stream", e);
        }
        mmInStream = tmpIn;
        mmOutStream = tmpOut;
        BtBus.subscribe(action -> {
           if(action instanceof BtAction){
               write(((BtAction) action).getAction().getBytes());
           }
        });
    }

    public void run() {
        mmBuffer = new byte[1024];
        int numBytes; // bytes returned from read()
        // Keep listening to the InputStream until an exception occurs.
        while (true) {
            try {
                // Read from the InputStream.
                numBytes = mmInStream.read(mmBuffer);
                // Send the obtained bytes to the UI activity.
                BtAction action = BtCommFilter.getActionType(mmBuffer);
                BtBus.publish(action);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Input stream was disconnected", e);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Call this from the main activity to send data to the remote device.
    public void write(byte[] bytes) {
        try {
            mmOutStream.write(bytes);
            // Share the sent message with the UI activity.
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error occurred when sending data", e);
            // Send a failure message back to the activity.
        }
    }

    // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
    public void cancel() {
        try {
            mmSocket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Could not close the connect socket", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the stack relevant stack trace from the exception

```
E/BluetoothService: Error occurred when sending data
java.io.IOException: socket closed
at android.net.LocalSocketImpl$SocketOutputStream.write(LocalSocketImpl.java:130)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket.write(BluetoothSocket.java:659)
at android.bluetooth.BluetoothOutputStream.write(BluetoothOutputStream.java:85)
at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:82)
at com.medspark.tenscontroller.service.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread.write(BluetoothService.java:183)
at com.medspark.tenscontroller.service.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread.lambda$new$0$BluetoothService$ConnectedThread(BluetoothService.java:157)
at com.medspark.tenscontroller.service.BluetoothService$ConnectedThread$$Lambda$0.accept(Unknown Source)
at io.reactivex.internal.observers.LambdaObserver.onNext(LambdaObserver.java:60)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.drainNormal(ObservableObserveOn.java:200)
at io.reactivex.internal.operators.observable.ObservableObserveOn$ObserveOnObserver.run(ObservableObserveOn.java:252)
at io.reactivex.android.schedulers.HandlerScheduler$ScheduledRunnable.run(HandlerScheduler.java:109)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6872)
```

As you can see, when I close the connection the socket is properly closed and the thread is disposed of. When I reconnect a new socket is created and a new thread spun up, so I don't understand where the IOException is being thrown. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where us your connectSocket method?

Comment: @AlexeyOsminin I have added it in the code above, hope it helps